# pyplot.fill_between: ufunc 'isfinite' not supported for the input types,

Tags: python, matplotlib, charts

I'm having trouble getting the fill_between method to work properly.

Scenario: I'm trying to chart economic data (quarter by quarter) and I'm trying to highlight parts of the chart where the numbers are in decline vs. recovering/growing.

Here are the code snippets I'm working with.

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize = (15, 4))

#plot the vector
x = ['Q1 2000', 'Q2 2000', 'Q3 2000', 'Q4 2000', 'Q1 2001', 'Q2 2001', 'Q3 2001', 'Q4 2001', 'Q1 2002', 'Q2 2002', 'Q3 2002', 'Q4 2002', 'Q1 2003', 'Q2 2003', 'Q3 2003', 'Q4 2003', 'Q1 2004', 'Q2 2004', 'Q3 2004', 'Q4 2004', 'Q1 2005', 'Q2 2005', 'Q3 2005', 'Q4 2005', 'Q1 2006', 'Q2 2006', 'Q3 2006', 'Q4 2006', 'Q1 2007', 'Q2 2007', 'Q3 2007', 'Q4 2007']
y = [402487852, 412644261, 410514408, 413488734, 406660923, 412554119, 407651445, 406860089, 400229102, 407450305, 405037469, 406487811, 398565014, 405405583, 403636107, 406473546, 401454557, 409973402, 409031867, 413206392, 407925829, 416732737, 417266345, 420148526, 416358183, 424753488, 423598265, 426746034, 421871312, 429850192, 427422632, 430316935]
ax.plot(x = x, y = y , color = 'navy', linewidth = 2, alpha = 0.8, label = None)
        
#color the decline, recovery, and growth
ax.fill_between(x = ('Q4 2000', 'Q1 2003'), y1 = 398565014, y2 = 413488734
, color = 'red', alpha = 0.1, label = 'Decline')
ax.fill_between(x = ('Q1 2003', 'Q2 2005'), y1 = 398565014, y2 = 413488734, color = 'gold', alpha = 0.1, label = 'Recovery')
ax.fill_between(x = ('Q2 2005', 'Q2 2005'), y1 = 413488734, y2 = 413488734, color = 'green', alpha = 0.1, label = 'Growth')
```

That gives me the following:

[image: current_plot]

What I would like to do is shade only those areas between the "middle" line and the plotted line.

Comment: I get the below error:

```
operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (2,) (32,) 
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to make `fill_between()` only fill a part of the x-region, is:

- provide the x-values as numeric; the internal representation of the x-values for a categorical axis are just the numbers `0,1,2,...` (which coincides with `np.arange(len(x))`)
- as `y1` has all the y-values, all x-values need to be given
- the `where=` parameter can be used to select only a subset of the values

Here is some example code:

```py
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import ticker
import numpy as np

x = ['Q1 2000', 'Q2 2000', 'Q3 2000', 'Q4 2000', 'Q1 2001', 'Q2 2001', 'Q3 2001', 'Q4 2001', 'Q1 2002', 'Q2 2002',
     'Q3 2002', 'Q4 2002', 'Q1 2003', 'Q2 2003', 'Q3 2003', 'Q4 2003', 'Q1 2004', 'Q2 2004', 'Q3 2004', 'Q4 2004',
     'Q1 2005', 'Q2 2005', 'Q3 2005', 'Q4 2005', 'Q1 2006', 'Q2 2006', 'Q3 2006', 'Q4 2006', 'Q1 2007', 'Q2 2007',
     'Q3 2007', 'Q4 2007']
y = [402487852, 412644261, 410514408, 413488734, 406660923, 412554119, 407651445, 406860089, 400229102, 407450305,
     405037469, 406487811, 398565014, 405405583, 403636107, 406473546, 401454557, 409973402, 409031867, 413206392,
     407925829, 416732737, 417266345, 420148526, 416358183, 424753488, 423598265, 426746034, 421871312, 429850192,
     427422632, 430316935]

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(15, 4))

ax.plot(x, y, color='navy', linewidth=2, alpha=0.8, label=None)

xi = np.arange(len(x))
ax.fill_between(x=xi, y1=y, y2=413488734, color='red', alpha=0.1, label='Decline',
                where=(xi >= x.index('Q4 2000')) & (xi <= x.index('Q1 2003')))
ax.fill_between(x=xi, y1=y, y2=413488734, color='gold', alpha=0.1, label='Recovery',
                where=(xi >= x.index('Q1 2003')) & (xi <= x.index('Q2 2005')))
ax.fill_between(x=xi, y1=y, y2=413488734, color='green', alpha=0.1, label='Growth',
                where=(xi >= x.index('Q2 2005')) & (xi <= x.index('Q4 2007')))
ax.margins(x=0)
ax.tick_params(axis='x', labelrotation=45)
ax.yaxis.set_major_formatter(ticker.FuncFormatter(lambda x, pos: f'{x:,.0f}'))
ax.legend()
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image: example plot]

Comment: This looks like it works, but I need to verify it functions correctly within my class object. I will check/upvote once I complete it. TY!

Comment: The problem seems to be `test.y` which should be numerical for `fill_between` to work correctly. Can you convert it? E.g. `y = np.array(y, dtype=int)`

Comment: yes that works, I've edited the class object to only capture numeric values. I;m testing the rest of it now.